# Angularjs connect run variable to controller

Tags: angularjs

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $location, Data) {
        $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            Data.get('session').then(function (results) {
                if (results.uid) {
                    $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                    $rootScope.uid = results.uid;
                    $rootScope.name = results.name;
                    $rootScope.email = results.email;
                } else {
                    var nextUrl = next.$$route.originalPath;
                    if (nextUrl == '/signup' || nextUrl == '/login') {

                    } else {
                        $location.path("/login");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

now what i want to do with $rootscope.authenticated is hide a menu based on true or false

```
<div ng-hide="" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li><a href="#/dashboard">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#/meldingen">Meldingen</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#/about-us">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

this is the menu now i tried using ng-hide="authenticated" but it doesnt seem to work out and i dont have a clue on how to get the authenticated value to a controller

Hopefully you can help me out

Comment: Did you check in console if the $rootscope.authenticated values is true or false?

Comment: Have you tried doing that in Data itself, when you are establishing the session ?

Comment: I guess he probably be getting it false every time.

Comment: the true or false value showsup if i just run {{authenticated}} somewhere on the page but it doesnt seem to hide it when its false

Answer (score 0):

Inject `$rootScope` into controller and expose `authenticated` like this: `$scope.authenticated = $rootScope.authenticated`, make sure that the controller is available in that aprt of tempalte. I solved this in the past by having `AppCtrl` which was declared on the whole website in `<html ng-controller="AppCtrl">`

Comment: more better would have maintain service instead of `$rootScope`

Comment: Agreed, the best way to store and share state is through using of services!

Comment: Well frist I recommend you to make it run with the $rootScope, then you can refactor to use service. Then inject service in run block, createsome obejct in service for storing data and expose it, then inject it into contorller too. I wrote blog about similar topic - Model Pattern for Angular JS - https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/model-pattern-for-angular-js-67494389d6f

Comment: Just noticed that it works for other divs but not for the menu one and i have declared my app etc in the <Html> tag

Comment: Like create `AppCtrl` add it to the top level of DOM (aka html tag) and everything exposed through that cpontroller would be visible anywhere in the app